# Is there any wake to make view in laravel by command line?

Tags: laravel

I'm trying to make view in laravel by command line like:

> php artisan make:model
> php artisan make:controller
> php artisan make:view!

Comment: you could make a generator to make them .. though I dont see much reason, what would be in the stub for this view? what would be in it if you were to generate one?

Comment: What's the logic behind generating view using artisan command? Y are you looking for such a command? will it ease your work load? my answer is no. Its useless.

Answer (score 0):

You could install this [laravel manthra](https://github.com/nicoaudy/laravelmanthra). Config your own stub and start generating.